# Updating JIRA custom field with multi-line comments using Panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to update a JIRA custom field from a panda dataframe.

The attribute DATA_HISTORY contains the following values -

`update_dict[data_history] = df[df.EID==employee_id].DATA_HISTORY.values[0]`

**'01/18/2021: CRITICAL\r01/17/2021: HIGH'**

`issue.update(fields=update_dict)`

When I make an update to JIRA, the values are getting displayed in a single line. Could you please tell me how to update JIRA with a multi-line comment on the custom field? I would want the output to be displayed in the custom field as below -

**custom_field1  01/18/2021: CRITICAL 

               01/17/2021: HIGH**

Answer (score 0):

Using Jira REST API FOR adding comment, in the content block add

```
{
"type": "hardBreak"
}
```

to achieve this. This is as per Jira Atlassian Document Format (ADF) guidelines